# elegant way to pass operator to attribute in python

Tags: python

Basically my Question: Is there an elegant way, if I have a given Container class

```py
class Container:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

to pass any operator to the value parameter of the Container class?

So one obvious solution would be to override any single operator on its own. So for example for `+` I could do:

```py
class Container:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other
```

so that for example

```py
c1 = Container(1)
c1 += 1
print(c1)
```

would result in

```py
2
```

and

```py
c2 = Container("ab")
c2 += "c"
print(c2)
```

would result in

```py
abc
```

So what I could do is to override all arithmetic built-in functions from python. But my Question is, is there a more elegant (shorter) way to do this for any operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factor out some of the more repetitive boilerplate:

```
import operator


class Container:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def _generic_op(f):
        def _(self, other):
            return f(self.value, other)
        return _

    __add__ = _generic_op(operator.add)
    __sub__ = _generic_op(operator.sub)
    __mul__ = _generic_op(operator.mul)
    # etc

    # No need for _generic_op as a class attribute
    del _generic_op
```

Comment: thx, this is already a lot nicer than override all functions. I will way if someone has an even better idea. If not I'll except your answer

Answer (score 0):

If the number of overloads are smaller than the different classes you want to overload in, you can define saperate class for each overload and inherit it. So,

```py
class Adder:
    def __add__(self, val):
        self.value += val
        return self

class Subtractor:
    def __sub__(self, val):
        self.value -= val
        return self

class Foo(Adder, Subtractor):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

foo = Foo(5)
foo -= 3
foo += 7
print(foo.value)
```

But I am against doing such operations between custom DataTypes and native dataTypes. Consider this just a simple example that doesn't follow good coding principles in that sense.
If incase you still want to allow adding int/float directly, you might also want to handle Foo class objects inside too.

Comment: interesting, but no actually i want to do this for only one class.

Comment: Then you will have to do it the normal way I guess.